# Syntax error when using ? on end of property name in c# (.net 4.6 )

Tags: c#

What do I need to do to enable support for the new(ish) `?` at the end of variables/properties in c# ?

The following sample snippet :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
public class Foo {

   [DataMember( Name = "available?" )]
   public bool available? { get; set; }

}
```

Produces the following syntax error in the code view :

[image]

### More information

This started out as I copied the json data from the **A request of "google.com" would return** section on [jsonwhois.net/docs](https://jsonwhois.com/docs), and pasted it into [jsonutils.com](http://jsonutils.com/) with the following options :

[image: jsonutils parameters]

Which output a nice DataContract for me, but some of the properties were using the `?` null/or qualifier, and the IDE doesn't seem to register them.  Is there a reference or something I need to add ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130910/discussion-on-question-by-samuel-jackson-syntax-error-when-using-on-end-of-pro).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `?` token *does not* go at the **end** of a property/method name, except when acting as a null-propagation operator.

There are several situations where a `?` symbol is a valid token in C#, the most common:

- Syntax-sugar for `Nullable<T>` on a value-type declaration (`public int? NullableInteger { get; set; }`)
- Use in a ternary-operator / inline-`if` (`a == b ? 0 : 5`)
- A null-propagation operator (C#6.0 feature) to act as syntax-sugar for null-checks before method/property calls (`someNullableType?.Property`)

I'm not sure which one you wanted, probably the first.

---

Since you updated the question:

The website you used (`jsonutils.com`) gave you malformed C#. It failed to even *attempt* to validate that the property names that it gave you, and instead just plopped whatever identifiers it found in the C# and said "yeah it's fine". Not good at all.

If your JSON data has a question-mark as a property name, you should leave it in the `DataMember` declaration, but remove it from the C# property.

```
[DataMember(Name = "available?")]
public bool Available { get; set; }
```

In C# a property/method identifier cannot have a very large list of symbols present in it, basically none except an underscore (`_`). (I'm not counting numbers as symbols, by the way.) What this means, is that when we have to work with data (JSON, XML, etc.) that has a identifier in it that is malformed for C# (valid for JSON if in quotes) such as `available?`, we have to work around that.

This is what `DataMember(Name = "available?")` attribute is for. We use this to indicate that the item in the JSON we want is `available?`, but it goes in the `Available` property in our C#. This is *really* common with web-based JSON, and since my first JSON + C# encounter I've never omitted `DataMemberAttribute` from **anything**.

In this case, `available?` doesn't *look* like it's null, but I could be wrong. You shouldn't need `bool?`, should just be `bool`.

If I am wrong and `Available` is nullable, then it's `public bool? ...`.

---

If you look at your JSON (which is pretty handy - write these classes yourself, web-generators aren't great) you'll see:

> ```
> "available?": false,
> "registered?": true,
> ```

The corresponding C# properties are:

```
[DataMember(Name = "available?")]
public bool Available { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "registered?")]
public bool Registered { get; set; }
```

Comment: The generator does take the bulk of the work out having to tab back and forth between pretty-formatted json, scroll up for larger blocks, and source class only to find that you missed a parameter causing the entire contract to fail.  Swapping out a few `?` is rather trivial and more reliable (especially with json that cascades much deeper like some of the blizzard api)

Comment: I'd argue that since you're giving it a `[DataMember]` attribute you might as well give it a convention-compliant identifier, and call it `IsAvailable` (and `IsRegistered`). But nice answer.